# Android Studio Canary freezes all the time on Windows 10 64-bit

Tags: android, android-studio, canary-deployment

I am currently developing an Android App. Four days ago I messed up the Git repository I was working with and I decided to create a new Android Studio project and clone the repository inside this new project.
Since then Android Studio freezes like every 2 - 10 Minutes. I even installed Canary 12 for that reason, I tried to remove everything I found regarding Android on my Computer before! Nevertheless, I still get those freezes.

I already set memory to maximum. At the time Android Studio crashes the total memory consumption is not above 50%, so it can't be a memory problem (in my opinion) - any ideas?

Comment: It's not related to Android Studio Canary, as you mentioned ` I even installed Canary 12 for that reason`. Instead, try figuring out what you did to cause the issue. If all else fails, reinstall Android Studio and import the library as a module instead..

Comment: What do you mean with `import the library as a module instead`?

Comment: How am I supposed to find out what is wrong if Android Studio freezes without any error message? Just a garbage piece of software

Comment: Did you reinstall Android Studio (stable version) and try to run without the repository?

Comment: I downloaded Android Studio 3.5, installed it and loaded the previous project from Canary

Answer (score -1):

I would try File > Invalidate cache and restart, maybe disable all non included extensions. if that does not work try restarting your computer and/or reinstall android studio.

Comment: As I mentioned, I moved from regular Android Studio to the Canary version (e.g. reinstalling Android Studio). A fun side note: I just tried to `Invalidate Cache and Restart' and just after clicking the button, Android Studio freezed. I don't know how Google is able to release such a software

Comment: try installing stable android studio see if it works (I thought you were running stable and canary side by side)

Comment: I installed stable Android Studio now and the problem still persists

Comment: I installed `Java SDK 8u221` - didn't change anything